# Add AUTO INCREMENT column to Sqlite View

Tags: sql, sqlite, view

I have a table lets called it myTable

```
tID    Name   Degree
1          A         23
2          B         55
3          C         77
4          D         45
```

I want to select only pass Degrees in New **View** lets call it `MyView`

The result will be

```
tID    Name     Degree
---    ----    --------
2      B        55
3      C        77
```

But I want `myView` have sequences start from one by one as follows:

```
index   Name    Degree
-----   ----    ------
 1       B       55
 2       C       77
```

It's possible?
I need to do this because I have a the original table have:

```
tID  sID  Name Lesson TryNo Degree           
1     1     A    a1     1       23
2     1     A    a1     2       66
3     2     A    b1     1       55
4     2     A    b1     2       77
```

I want to select max  tries degree for every lesson exams for each student. ex:

```
tID  sID  Name Lesson TryNo Degree           
2     1     A    a1     2       66

4     2     A    b1     2       77
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of this `index` column? And it's bad name for a column.

Comment: Actually the Index just a name, I like to make this sequences because i have tow similar views, and i want to join them by this Index

Comment: Can you expand your question with info about what you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Alxender, I add more details about what I really want to do

Comment: You did not explain which two views you want to join. (And such an index value would not help with joining.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible directly since View is just a mirror representation of your tables.

View is created using **Select** statements, as far as I remember, it is not possible to have a select statement with variables.

Comment: Thanks, Yes but It's possible to add new column and fill it with a value which repeated through all records ex: CREATE VIEW [My_VIEW] AS 
SELECT 1 id, Degree Degree FROM myTable

Comment: sorry mis interpreted questions here is a hint http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d0a2d/55 @user3398078

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

```
CREATE or replace VIEW myView AS 
SELECT rownum  id, 
       marks, 
       name    
  FROM studentinfo 
 WHERE degree>50
```

Comment: have you tried using row_num() analytical function ?